# getchar to read from command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-interface, getchar

I want to get my program to use the command line arguments with getchar to then encode a message. My problem is that getchar is only paying attention to what I type after the program has executed. How can I make it read the command line arguments instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pin, charin, charout;

    // this verifies that a key was given at for the first argument
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 0){
        printf("ERROR, no key was found..");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        srand(atoi(argv[1]));
        pin = rand() % 27;
    }
    while( (charin=getchar()) != EOF){
        charout = charin + pin;
        putchar(charout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont get it, the program recieves its argument via argv, you have them there, what is it that you are trying to read?

Comment: you are reading correctly your command line input, what do you want to do ?

Comment: have you specified the commandline arguments? simply running the code from an IDE would not do that. also **My problem is that getchar is only paying attention to what I type after the program has executed.**, what does that even mean?

Comment: This question is somewhat confusing but I'm guessing you want to compare a randomly generated data with one from program arguments. Make use of strcmp to check strings and sprintf to make a string from an integer.

Comment: in general, do not ever use a argv[] value greater than `argv[0]` until have examining `argc` to assure the desired argument exists.   BTW: when the desired command line argument does not exist, output a 'usage' message to let the user know what went wrong.

Comment: this line: `charout = charin + pin;` will not `wrap` around the printable characters,  so some characters, like 'z' for example, will be trying to output unprintable values (assuming ASCII)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getchar to read from command line arguments

That's the problem - if you are getting command line arguments you don't do it with `getchar`: use `argc` to get the count of arguments and `argv[]` to get particular arguments.

I don't think you need `getchar` in this program at all.

These are also good suggestions, please take a look at the parts about argument handling:

[encode program using getchar from command line argument and putchar to send to decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427784/encode-program-using-getchar-from-command-line-argument-and-putchar-to-send-to-d)

I think you are trying to write a program that behaves like this:

`program pin message`

and then it will use some sort of Caesar cipher on `message` to obfuscate the output. Is that right?

If so, then you need to also get `argv[2]` and use `printf` to output the results.